# SQL parser for formula passed as parameter

Tags: sql, parsing, replace, formula

I have been tasked with writing a stored procedure that takes a user specified formula as parameter, and does calculations using tables on the formula.

It's for the result of a competency test. The test is broken up into sections and each section is assigned a variable, eg. `E1` and `E2`.

Now each section consists of questions with their scores. eg. `E1 = [1]+[2]-[3]+[4]+[5]+[6]` when the `[number]` indicates the question number.

Now the user will specify a formula like the above `[1]+[2]-[3]+[4]+[5]+[6]`, and I have to write a parser that replaces the question number with the score for that question. But there is a snag in it, because one section can reference the score of another section eg. `E2 = [7]+[8]+([6]-E1)+[9]`.

So I need to write a parser that parses the string, replaces the [Number] with the score, and if it hits a variable number, first calculates the sections score, before continuing.

I can imagine that it will be something like a recursive function, but can anyone help me oin the right direction?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not saying you can't do it, but SQL is not the best environment for this kind of operation; equally, you can bash a nail into a wall using a watermelon. You don't specify your particular platform - if it is Microsoft SQL then perhaps a SQL CLR procedure would make the necessary manipulations easier.

Comment: +1 I often say SQL is designed for manipulating data, not for manipulating code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mssql - then you can also utilize *dynamic sql* such as `exec('select 2*2')`